# Difference-in-Differences without an exogenous shock?

Tags: difference-in-difference, endogeneity

First time post! In any case, I'm struggling to solve the endogeneity problem in one of my studies. I have found a series of top papers (in accounting, finance, and economics) that utilize a rather odd (but very logical in my opinion) Difference-in-Differences (DD) approach. However, while these top studies use the approach, *they do not really explain themselves theoretically.*

Basically, these papers (e.g., Francis et al. 2015 referenced below) employ DD without a real exogenous shock. They utilize countless employee turnover events regardless of whether they are endogenous or not (though some papers focus on death-based samples, I cannot and most do not). For example, in Francis et al. (2015) they state (in response to the listed endogeneity issues): "To mitigate these issues, we use a difference-indifferences framework for our empirical tests, comparing activity before and after transitions from a male to a female executive with a control sample of male-to-male transition firms."

This approach would work in my setting (which is similar), I just feel uncomfortable using an approach that I cannot find explicit theoretical support for. I'm used to DD papers that have a (somewhat) clear exogenous shock like a minimum wage change or a certain training program applied to one division of a company. All well cited DD tutorial papers mirror this general approach (in my discipline at least).

Can any of you set me straight and give me some reputable sources (any discipline) that explain why this approach is OK (despite no exogenous shock)? This endogeneity issue is killing me...

Reference: 
Francis, B., Hasan, I., Park, J. C., & Wu, Q. (2015). Gender differences in financial reporting decision making: Evidence from accounting conservatism. Contemporary Accounting Research, 32(3), 1285-1318.

Comment: DD allows for strategic/non-random/confounded selection into the treatment group, provided this selection is not time-varying.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there any source that addresses this explicitly that I can cite?

Comment: I really like Jeff Wooldridge's Econometric Analysis of Cross Section and Panel Data on this topic. He also has some great lecture notes (with Guido Imbens) on the web.