# Can I use an instrumental variable to control for treatment endogeneity in differences-in-differences model?

Tags: econometrics, panel-data, instrumental-variables, difference-in-difference

I have panel data with two time periods (pre and post) and two groups (treatment and control). I have a differences-in-differences model with the standard estimating equation:

\begin{equation}
y_{it} = \beta_0 + X_{it} \beta_1 + \gamma_1 T + \gamma_2 P + \theta T \cdot P + \epsilon_{it}
\end{equation}
where $T$ is an indicator for the treatment group, $P$ is an indicator for the post period, $T \cdot P$ is the interaction, and $X_{it}$ are exogenous controls. Unfortunately, I have reason to be concerned about endogeneity between the assignment into treatment/control groups and the outcome.

I have an instrument $z_i$ (it does not vary over time) that satisfies the exclusion restriction in that it only affects $y_{it}$ through the assignment into the treatment or control group. Is there any way to combine the instrumental variables framework with a differences-in-differences framework to handle this endogeneity?

---

Is this even something I should be concerned about? Maybe it means the DID model won't be estimating the average treatment effect, but if it isn't possible to use IV here, should I be worried?

I searched through Woolridge's econometric text *Econometric Analysis of Cross Section and Panel Data*, specifically Chapter 18, which discusses average treatment effects and endogeneity, but there isn't any mention of DID models in the book. Other related questions ([this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/351513/41138) and [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/353506/41138)) have been asked, but there are no answers thus far.

Comment: If your endogeneity is time-invariant, the differencing would wipe it out. If it is not time-invariant, I am not sure you could handle it with a time-invariant IV.

Comment: The above comment about differencing assumes that you are fitting the DID using panel fixed effects approach.